# Creating a Typing Assist in Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I want to create a typing assisting addon to my Firefox such that whatever the user is typing currently appears on a small window on the right hand side bottom in bigger fonts.

This will help slow typists to type at a faster rate.

For example, when the user is on yahoo sign-up page and text box name, a small window should appear on the bottom right corner and should display the text he is entering in larger fonts. In this manner, the user can keep typing without moving his head up.

I have no experience with firefox addons, so I would like to know whether this project is feasible. If it is, then I would like to know whether it's possible to do with only JavaScript; or if I will have to use jQuery.

It will be much appreciated if you can provide some guidance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's feasible. You never *have* to use jQuery and it's not very useful when writing an add-on anyway, since you don't care about differences between browsers.

I suggest you start with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/ , try to get a page-mod running, make it handle keystrokes and display them in a <div> on the web page it's running in.